# How To Move Product Variation Descriptions in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to move my product's variation descriptions in Woocommerce beneath the add to cart button, and I can't find what hook I'm supposed to use. These are the variation's custom descriptions that load on selection in AJAX.

I'm able to hook another custom function beneath the add to cart button. So I think my problem is not knowing the name of the hook and/or if it's a hook versus a filter.  I *think* it's either `woocommerce_before_single_variation` or `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button`.

Here's several attempts I've tried before with no luck in `functions.php`:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation','woocommerce_single_product_summary', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',  9 );

//try #2
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20);
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 35);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality I was looking for is included in WooCommerce 2.4 as a default but is *not* done on a hook. It's added by jQuery updating a div instead - which I found in `woocommerce/js/assets/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js`. So I moved the div's location instead:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_after_single_variation', 'move_descriptions', 50);
function move_descriptions() {
    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description" style="border: 1px solid transparent; height: auto;"></div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do,

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20); 
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt');
```

Only move Short description if product is variable

```
add_action('wp_head', 'move_short_desc_for_varition');
function move_short_desc_for_varition() {
    #
    global  $post;
    $product = get_product( $post->ID );
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){ 
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20); 
        add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and I'm getting duplicate descriptions now. See [here](http://www.cchcollection.com.php53-13.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/product/kenan-jacket) . Leads me to think that the remove_action call isn't working but the add_action call is

Comment: ```woocommerce_template_single_excerpt``` is the product description hook on ```woocommerce_single_product_summary``` reference can be found on ```/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php``` line 53, 
checkout the demo http://demo2.woothemes.com/storefront/product/navy-floral-dress/ the product description is wrap with ```<div itemprop="description"></div>``` while yours is not, which simply means the additional description that is showing is not loaded by woocommerce default,

Comment: I realized that the product I linked you earlier had a short description displaying below the "Add to Cart" button, and made it appear that it was duplicating. Now that I've removed it, the code above isn't working. I tracked the div it is wrapped in to `/woocommerce/templates/singe-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` line 44. It's called `single_variation_wrap` , which is also where the hooks for single variation products are listed.

Comment: what I'm saying is the first description showing on your single product page is not from woocommerce default template but probably fired on a hook somewhere, as the default description is wrap with ```<div itemprop="description"></div>```

Comment: I have tried this with all plugins but WC turned off and Twenty Fifteen as the default template and it's still showing up the unique variable product descriptions in `<div class="woocommerce-variation-description"></div>` div. Is there something else with hooks that I'm missing?

Comment: you sure you're using latest woocommerce without template modification, you can try a clean set-up and compare it with your current set-up

Comment: Rereading my initial post, I think I'm explaining things imprecisely. I'm trying to move the variation descriptions (that are customized for a product variation and load via AJAX when you change selections) below the "Add to Cart" button. I've updated the main question to reflect this!

Comment: Ajax is never been a default functionality that display the description,  you need to dig into that  function which is connected to ajax request and edit/change/remove where the custom description display is being hooked and fired via ajax

Comment: For anyone else stumbling upon this, when you remove a hook you need to match the priority exactly otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the priority of the remove hook.

I give you an example (this work for me):

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

Pay attention and try with differents priorities.