# Move Variation Description to below the title on Single Product Page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to move the variation description from the product-summary to below the title and above the price.

I have tried this code:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'move_variation_description', 50);

function move_variation_description(){ 
  // Remove the hook from the original location
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( 
WC_Variation_Description::get_instance()->frontend, 
'add_variation_description' ), 25 );
  // Re-add the hook to where you want it to be
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary',  array( 
WC_Variation_Description::get_instance()->frontend, 
'add_variation_description' ), 25 );
}
```

But without any success. Code from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831995/how-to-move-product-variation-descriptons-in-woocommerce) doesn't seem to work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can override woocommerce template. Create a folder named woocommerce in your theme and further corresponding folders where relevant file is added in woocommmerce plugin. e.g woocommerce/single-product/layouts/ where product.php is added. 
In that overridden file you can move the variation description from the product-summary to below the title and above the price by changing the HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your answer TBI. I achieved it by using a function in functions.php

Answer (score 1):

Achieved it using the code below in functions.php

```
//Move Variation Description
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ec_child_modify_wc_variation_desc_position' );
function ec_child_modify_wc_variation_desc_position() {
    ?>
    <script>
    (function($) {
        $(document).on( 'found_variation', function() {
            var desc = $( '.woocommerce-variation.single_variation' ).find( 
'.woocommerce-variation-description' ).html();
            var $entry_summary = $( '.product_title' ), $wc_var_desc = 
$entry_summary.find( '.woocommerce-variation-description' );

            if ( $wc_var_desc.length == 0 ) {
                $entry_summary.append( '<div class="woocommerce-variation-
description"></div>' );
            }
            $entry_summary.find( '.woocommerce-variation-description' 
).html( desc );
        });
    })( jQuery );

    </script>
    <style>form.variations_form .woocommerce-variation-description { 
display: none; }</style>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Ok that is great but if it takes time i.e js works after page load then you can use overriding methods also. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky to achieve this since the variation description seems to be bundled up with the "add to cart" button. I have achieved this using the following method (explanations at the end):

1. You need to remove the product short description as this always goes above the variation description. Just add:

   `add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'single_product_summary_action', 1 );

   function single_product_summary_action() {
           // remove the single_excerpt
           //(we will manually add it back in the add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button)
           remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary',
                         'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
       }`
2. You need to override the WooCommerce template for variation "add to cart" button. You do this by making a copy of the WooCommerce file `templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php` in your theme.
   In that new file search for the line

   `do_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity');`

And add this right after it:

```
woocommerce_template_single_excerpt();
```

This will add the product short description back in.

In this way the variation description will be moved up.

Please note that:
- this solution moves the short description, not the variation description. But the end result is that the variation description will be moved up also.
- take a look at the WooCommerce file  `templates/content-single-product.php`. This specifies the order in which WC loads the various parts of the templates via the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action. That's where I got the `20` for the remove action.