# Conditionally display variation descriptions on woocommerce product pages

Tags: php, woocommerce, conditional-statements, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to hide the variation description on product pages if the variation's stock is >=1. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831995/how-to-move-product-variation-descriptions-in-woocommerce) I have made this code which is not working:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_after_single_variation', 'hide_descriptions', 10);

function hide_descriptions() {

    $stock_qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();
   
    if ($stock_qty>=1)
     ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description" style="display: none!important;"></div>
    <?php
    
}
```

I've also tried with the action hook  `'woocommerce_single_variation'` since the `class="woocommerce-variation-description"` is located inside the `class="woocommerce-variation single_variation"` - and the latter class is called by the `function woocommerce_single_variation()`.

But how do you access a nested class with a hook that targets its parent?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I see you didnt have opening and closing if brackets. And u wrote greater, not lower than 1, and try to use same priority as mentioned in the answer you looked up - 50.

```
 add_action ('woocommerce_after_single_variation', 'hide_descriptions', 50);

function hide_descriptions() {

    $stock_qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();
   
    if ($stock_qty < 2) { ?>

       <div class="woocommerce-variation-description" style="display:none"></div>
 
<?php }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, I still get the "there's a critical error" message. I think it might be because my site is using Ajax